# Switch between python 2.7 and python 3.5 on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, terminal

I generally use Python 2.7 but recently installed Python 3.5 using Miniconda on Mac OS X. Different libraries have been installed for these two versions of python. Now, the entering either of the keywords 'python' or 'python3' in terminal invokes python 3.5, and 'python2' returns '-bash: python2: command not found'. How can I now invoke them specifically using aliases 'python2' and 'python3' respectively?

I am currently using OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Have you tried `python -2`?

Comment: Sounds like you should open a bug report with Miniconda that they are not following [PEP-0394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

Comment: What do you mean by switching between them? Do you want to be able to invoke Python 2 specifically, when you want it, and invoke Python 3 specifically when you want that version? That you can do using the aliases `python2` and `python3` (and I'll post that as an answer if this is what you want and you edit your question accordingly). Or do you want to switch which version of Python actually runs when you type just `python`?

Comment: even if your able to run `python2` you might need to re-install things for python 2 it seems...

Answer (score 84):

IMHO, the best way to use two different Python versions on macOS is via `homebrew`. After [installing homebrew](http://brew.sh/) on macOS, run the commands below on your terminal.

```
brew install python@2
brew install python
```

Now you can run Python 2.7 by invoking `python2` or Python 3 by invoking `python3`. In addition to this, you can use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage different versions of `python` environments.

I have never personally used [`miniconda`](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) but from [the documentation,](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/test-drive.html) it looks like it is similar to using `pip` and `virtualenv` in combination.

Comment: how does one install things for python2 now?

Comment: pip2 install <package_name>

Answer (score 14):

OSX's Python binary (version 2) is located at `/usr/bin/python`

if you use `which python` it will tell you where the `python` command is being resolved to. Typically, what happens is third parties redefine things in `/usr/local/bin` (which takes precedence, by default over `/usr/bin`). To fix, you can either run `/usr/bin/python` directly to use 2.x or find the errant redefinition (probably in `/usr/local/bin` or somewhere else in your `PATH`)

Comment: But, I'm looking for the way to create an alias, say `python2` to invoke Python 2 and `python3` to invoke Python 3. Could you give me some information on that direction? Thnx.

Answer (score 5):

I already had python3 installed(via miniconda3) and needed to install python2 alongside in that case `brew install python` won't install python2, so you would need
`brew install python@2` .

Now alias `python2` refers to python2.x from `/usr/bin/python`

and alias `python3` refers to python3.x from `/Users/ishandutta2007/miniconda3/bin/python`

and alias `python` refers to python3 by default.

Now to use `python` as alias for python2, I added the following to `.bashrc` file

`alias python='/usr/bin/python'`.

To go back to python3 as default just remove this line when required.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to set the Python version back to 2.7 if you have installed Anaconda3 (Python 3.6) on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5.

1. Edit the **.bash_profile** file in your home directory.
2. `vi $HOME/.bash_profile`
3. Comment out the line with `anaconda3` addition to your `PATH` like this:

   ```
   # export PATH="/Users/YOURUSERNAME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
   ```
4. Close the shell, then open it again
5. You should now see 2.7 when you run `python`

Then, if you want 3.6 you can simply uncomment out the `anaconda3` line in your **.bash_profile**.

Trying to unlink `python` will end in tears in Mac OS X.

You will get something like this

```
unlink: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to John Wilkey's answer I would run python2 by finding `which python`, something like using `/usr/bin/python` and then creating an **alias** in `.bash_profile`:

`alias python2="/usr/bin/python"`

I can now run python3 by calling `python` and python2 by calling `python2`.

Answer (score 1):

I just follow up the answer from @John Wilkey.

My alias `python` used to represent python2.7 (located in `/usr/bin`).
However the default python_path is now preceded by `/usr/local/bin` for `python3`; hence when typing `python`, I didn't get either the python version.

I tried make a link in `/usr/local/bin` for `python2`:

`ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/`

It works when calling `python` for `python2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Apple’s system install of Python 2.7, be aware that it doesn’t quite follow the naming standards laid out in [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

In particular, it includes the optional symlinks with suffix `2.7` that you’re told not to rely on, and does not include the recommended symlinks with suffix `2` that you’re told you *should* rely on.

---

If you want to fix this, while sticking with Apple’s Python, you can create your own symlinks:

```
$ cd <somewhere writable and in your PATH>
$ ln -s /usr/bin/python python2
```

Or aliases in your bash config:

```
alias python2 python2.7
```

And you can do likewise for Apple’s 2to3, easy_install, etc. if you need them.

You shouldn’t try to put these symlinks into `/usr/bin`, and *definitely* don’t try to rename what’s already there, or to change the distutils setup to something more PEP-compliant. Those files are all part of the OS, and can be used by other parts of the OS, and your changes can be overwritten on even a minor update from 10.13.5 to 10.13.6 or something, so leave them alone and work around them as described above.

---

Alternatively, you could:

- Just use `python2.7` instead of `python2` on the command line and in your shbangs and so on.
- Use virtual environments or conda environments. The global `python`, `python3`, `python2`, etc. don’t matter when you’re always using the activated environment’s local `python`.
- Stop using Apple’s 2.7 and instead install a whole other 2.7 alongside it, as most of the other answers suggest. (I don’t know why so many of them are also suggesting that you install a second 3.6. That’s just going to add even *more* confusion, for no benefit.)