# How to install python 3x on Mac without overwriting 2.7 installation?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, python-2.7, macos-high-sierra

As Mac comes preinstalled with Python per this:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

I also need to have Python 3.x installed for software that specifically calls for it. How do I install the 3x version without overwriting my Python 2.7.14 version?

I'm planning on download/installing Python 3.x from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/).

I've found this [information](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html) but it doesn't seem to say that the process will not overwrite my existing Python

My Mac has High Sierra installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Homebrew to install both Python 2 and 3 on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671253/how-can-i-use-homebrew-to-install-both-python-2-and-3-on-mac)

Comment: Thanks I will try its instructions. Didn't come across this link.

Comment: here's another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680228/switch-between-python-2-7-and-python-3-5-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks this worked for me from  stackoverflow.com/questions/34680228/… suggested by wpercy. Specifically, brew update and brew install python3

Comment: Python also offers [official installers for MacOS](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/).