# python 2.7 and 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, chromium

I currently have Python 3.6.5 installed on my MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra (10.13.6). However, I am now working on a project that involves Google Chrome, and to check out and build Chromium I need Python 2.7. I still need 3.6.5 for other things though, specifically for a programming class I'm taking this semester, so how can I install Python 2.7 on my machine and use it concurrently with 3.6.5 so that I can use 2.7 to build Chromium and 3.6.5 for other projects? Is this doable? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just install both. If you have a well equipped IDE to use like PyCharm, just select it as the environment you want to use when creating your project. If you look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680228/switch-between-python-2-7-and-python-3-5-on-mac-os-x), you will get some good info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between python 2.7 and python 3.5 on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680228/switch-between-python-2-7-and-python-3-5-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thank you. So in the process of building Chromium I have to execute in the command line "$ fetch chromium". I now have Python 2.7 installed, but how can I ensure that when I say "fetch chromium", the files are executed in Python 2.7? I apologize, I haven't had to do anything like this before, so I'm having to learn on the fly and as a result have many dumb questions.