# Changing the default python version on Mac - Installing Biopython

Tags: python-3.x, macos, biopython

My Mac came installed with python 2.7 as the default python version. But, this version is no longer supported by many packages and software. I searched several online forums regarding how to change the default python version on mac. But, none of them seem to work. I also installed the latest version of python, and if I type:

> python --version

It returns the version as python 3.8. But if I try to install packages like Biopython, I get an error like this -

> defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable
>
> Collecting biopython Using cached biopython-1.77.tar.gz (16.8 MB)
>
> **ERROR**: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>
> Biopython requires Python 3.6 or later. **Python 2.7 detected**

I am really finding it difficult to install many packages required for my work. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly are you attempting to install it?

Comment: Hello, I am using the following command - pip install biopython. If any changes are to be made, please let me know

Comment: Whichever `pip` you are running apparently belongs to Python 2.7. Does it help if you use `pip3`? Or the full path to your 3.8 `pip`? Or the full path to Python 3.8 followed by `-m pip`?

Comment: Hello, I tried using **pip3 install biopython**, and biopython was installed. But, if I try to run a simple script, I am getting this error : [ImportError: No module named Bio]

Comment: We really need to see more details about where each version of Python is installed, what your `sys.path` looks like, and where the modules are installed. All of this should be easy to find from numerous duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much @tripleee. The error was with the command. I used to type [python script.py] and it was throwing this error -  [ImportError: No module named Bio]. But, when I executed this command - [python3 script.py], biopython worked. Now, biopython works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch between python 2.7 and python 3.5 on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680228/switch-between-python-2-7-and-python-3-5-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Hello, I have already tried the method mentioned in the link provided by you [Switch between python 2.7 and python 3.5 on Mac OS X]...I am using Mac OS BigSur and it did not work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you just have to change your Python symbolic link.

Please check this, and you will get it: https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf

Comment: Hello, I have already tried the method suggested by you and that is the reason why I am getting python 3.8, when I type the following command (python --version). But, when I try to install Biopython using (pip install biopython) - I am getting the above error and biopython throws an error saying that my 'default version of python is 2.7'.

Comment: that's because your pip is also a symbolic link to your python 2.7 instalation. Try "pip3 install biopython" and it will work. Also, to make your pip command point to pip3, please follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455001/how-to-change-pip3-command-to-be-pip

Comment: Thank you for the response. @tripleee suggested the same solution before and I executed it and Biopython was successfully installed....Cheers:)