# Using Python3 on macOS as default but pip still get using python 2.7

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, python-wheel

I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.0.1.

I'm setting up a `virtual env`

```
$python3 -m venv $my_workdir)/.virtualenv
```

but getting this error at building `wheel` package:

```
building '_openssl' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/Users/engontang/devspace/energisme/terraform/tfwrapper-infra-pda/.wrapper/.virtualenv/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/_openssl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/_openssl.o -Wconversion -Wno-error=sign-conversion
  build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/_openssl.c:575:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
  #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1 

----------------------------------------

ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography

Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517) ... /
```

As `wheel` is prebuilt with `pip` I thought it could be a `pip` upgrade issue, so I checked my `pip` version :

```
$pip --version                                                                                                                                                                                                      
pip 20.2b1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2b1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
```

I don't understand why `python 2.7` is still mentionned above while my default python version is :

```
$python -V                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Python 3.8.2
```

Trying however to upgragde pip results in this :

```
$pip install --upgrade pip --user                                                                                                                                                                                   
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip, pip2 and pip2.7 are installed in '/Users/engontang/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-20.2.4
```

Using `pip3` command gives the same result. You can see the `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7` message above, and also `pip` still showing up the same version rather than `20.2.4`:

```
$pip --version                                                                                                                                                                                                       
pip 20.2b1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2b1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
```

And my `virtualenv` setup still lead to the same above error.

Can one here say why `pip` is still looking at `python 2.7` site packages, and what could be the problemm with `wheel` package build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65069019/changing-the-default-python-version-on-mac-installing-biopython

Comment: Don't use the system Python. Install Anaconda or Python through `brew`.

Answer (score 20):

For devices using Apple Silicon you may try this (as default homebrew bin directory differs)

```
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

You can view the command by yourself entering

```
brew info openssl
```

Comment: I did the `brew info openssl` and copied
 
```export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"```

and it at least got me past the missing header error. Thanks!

Comment: If you're installing an older version of `cryptography` (like 2.9.x) you *have* to link with `openssl@1.1` instead of `openssl@3`.

Comment: is this with the assumption that "brew install openssl" was run previously? It's not installed on my system att.

Answer (score 6):

Setting compilation Flags helped solving the `openssl` for `wheel` issue:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

But still don't understand the above described `pip` behavior.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day :) I'm just curious, how did you come to this solution? Which documentation indicated to use these flags?

Comment: Not the author, but `brew info openssl` will print out the env exports to run to get the flags :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Luca

1. Install python using `brew install python`
2. Check the location of the installed file `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python`
3. `ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python`
4. Check the version again `python --version`

And if you don't already have Homebrew installed on your mac, you can find the instructions here: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation